# Not properly add inputAccessoryView for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, inputaccessoryview

There is a requirement of `inputAccessoryView` is for the chat application.

When I add `inputAccessoryView` to `UITextField` on tap event of `UIButton`. That view is set as `inputAccessoryView` completely but text field is not becoming first responder.

(Note: Super view of `textfield` is viewText.)

```
- (IBAction)btnOpenTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIView *accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]init];
    accessoryView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, _viewText.frame.size.width, _viewText.frame.size.height);
    [accessoryView addSubview:_viewText];

    _txtMessage.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
    [_txtMessage becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dont add accessoryView to _ViewText

Comment: what is viewText exactly? Setting inputAccessoryView change the input view from keyboard to your custom view. Make sure your viewText is a proper view.

Comment: Have you tried to `removeFromSuperView` before adding `_viewText` as Subview to `accessoryView` . If you need _viewText as subview.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I can't do this because i want display '_viewText' in inputAccsoryView.

Comment: @shivam viewText is one view, that set on storyboard.

Comment: @Mrug i do this but not add in accsoryView.

Comment: But actually its wrong.. Your viewText is superView of TextField and then your are assigning it as subview of Accessary view of TextField.. thats not correct thing. Is there any specific reason of doing such recursion ?

Comment: @Mrug this functionality i want use for chatting application, i set 'viewText' on bottom of view and when user tap on button i want add viewText on inputaccessoryview.

Comment: @Mrug i remove _viewText from super view. then i add on inputaccesoryview.

Comment: then simply detach TextField from this flow. Do not subview TextField inside _viewText.

Comment: If you directly use the _viewText as inputAccessoryView, It will work fine.

Comment: @shivam sorry this solution is not working.

Comment: Its working in my case. Issue is something else in your code. Maybe accessoryView is not on top or check its alpha. Just go again with your code.

Comment: _viewText is superview of textfiled if you don't know then i tell you.

Comment: in UItextfiled you can set rightView/leftView you can solve your proble using this     txtSearch.rightView = MYBUTTON/OR VIEW;
    txtSearch.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya you not understand my problem.

Comment: Lol  just _txtMessage.inputAccessoryView = _viewText; You dont need to create another View containing _viewText  :D

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan _viewText is super view of _txtMessage.

Comment: you cannot add superview in subview

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan i remove _viewText from superview than after i add in subview.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `[_textMessage reloadInputViews]`, replacing `[_text becomeFirstResponder]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is quite not possible, this will cause recursion, alternatively what you can do is put a textfield on bottom of the screen and when the textfield is selected you can animate it up with the flow of the keyboard. i think this is an appropriate solution if i got your question correctly.

Comment: I can't do this because i want display '_viewText' in inputAccsoryView.

Comment: Then don't out TextField inside _viewText. keep it in some another View. This is causing Recursion.